# set Linearlayout's background that contains BottomNavigationView to transparent in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a `linearlayout` that holds inside it a `BottomNavigationView` (from Material Design Library v2)
There is `20dp` margin on `right` and `left` of `Linearlayout` so that bottom navigation appear floating, but linearlayout `background` is never transparent even if I set it to #00ffffff or @null

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/mainActivityConstraint">

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/MainLinearLayoutMainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mainActivityConstraint"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mainActivityConstraint">
  
       <!-- SOME CONTENT HERE, REMOVED FOR SIMPLIFICATION, HAS NO EFFECT ON LATER CODE -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:elevation="1dp"
            android:background="@null">


            <!-- Bottom Navigation Bar -->


            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
                style="@style/BottomNavigationCustomStyle"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_bottomnavigation_shape"
                android:padding="10dp"/>



            <!-- End of Bottom Navigation Bar -->



        </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>





</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white color is coming from some underlying view - either the parent of the *LinearLayout* (grandparent, etc.) or another view that is not in the ancestral chain but is positioned under the *LinearLayout*.

Use the Layout Inspector to look at your layout to identify the culprit. Once identified, you can take steps to get the transparency you want.

**Update**

So, let's track this down. I have made a quick replica of your posted layout. It looks like the following in the Layout Inspector:

[image]

We can also trace back through the view hierarchy from the *BottomNavigationView* to the top:

```
var v = binding.bottomNavigation as View?
while (v != null) {
    Log.d("Applog", "View id ${v.id} bg=${v.background}")
    v = v.parent as View?
}
```

This code displays the following:

```
D  View id 2131230820   bg=com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable@43872c4 [bottom_navigation]
D  View id -1 bg=null [Linearlayout]
D  View id 2131230727 bg=null [MainLinearLayoutMainActivity]
D  View id 2131230987 bg=null [mainActivityConstraint]
D  View id 16908290 bg=null [content]
D  View id 2131230778 bg=null [action_bar_root]
D  View id -1 bg=null [FrameLayout]
D  View id -1 bg=null [LinearLayout]
D  View id -1 bg=android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@698c5ad [DecorView - This ColorDrawable is "white"]
```

The bracketed comments are mine.

As you can see, all the views as we ascend through the hierarchy have a background of `null` except for the `BottomNavigationView` and the *DecorView* which encases the entire layout and is managed by Android.

The white space you reference comes from one of these two views and most likely the *DecorView*.

Comment: in Layout inspector, not much information I got there, main linearlayout with 2 child linearlayouts. I set both and main linearlayout to #00ffffff and still opaque white

Answer (score 1):

try this code (in linear layout)...

```
android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:elevation="1dp"    
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

instead of

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: I have tried that

Comment: Code updated . Kindly try this one

Comment: same result, it's still opaque white

Comment: can you change background color of inner_linear layout. So, we can see whether it works or not